# deleteObject not working as expected - Amazon S3 Java

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to delete a file from bucket using following code. but I can still view the file via browser

```
if (isValidFile(s3Client, BucketName, keyName)) {
    try{
        s3Client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(BucketName,keyName));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Why is delete not working??

Answer (score 0):

For me, working here is an option.

```
public boolean deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileUrl) {
        String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        try {
            DeleteObjectsRequest delObjReq = new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucketName).withKeys(fileName);
            s3client.deleteObjects(delObjReq);
            return true;
        } catch (SdkClientException s) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If the object is public, it may cached by browser. Besides, DELETE OBJECT operation is [eventual consistent](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_data_consistency_model_does_Amazon_S3_employ)